# Accessing properties from within a script tag in AEM sightly component

Tags: aem

I have the following Javascript code and I'm trying to make it dynamic within a sightly component.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#map').usmap({
    showLabels: true
});
</script>
```

I need the "true" to toggle based on a checkbox in the dialog. And it needs to be a boolean, not a string.

**example.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fillColor = '#${properties.fillColor @context="scriptString"}';
    var hoverColor = '#${properties.hoverColor @context="scriptString"}';
    var showStateLabels = '${properties.option2 @context="text"}';
    var defaultStateColor = ${properties.option2 ? '#fff' : '#AAA' @context='scriptString'};

    console.log("showStateLabels");

$('#map').usmap({
    showLabels: showStateLabels
});
</script>

<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**dialog.xml**

```
<option2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
    fieldLabel="Map Option 2?" 
    name="./option2" 
    width="150" 
    xtype="selection" 
    type="checkbox"/>
```

I'm able to get it to console.log "true" if the checkbox is checked, but nothing if the checkbox isn't checked.  How can I make this variable toggle true/false based on a dialog checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a question regarding Classic UI dialogs.

If so, please refer to: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/xtypes.html, see "checkbox" section.

your widget should have `xtype="checkbox"`
And the classic UI docs for it are here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Checkbox

you could try adding `defaultValue="false"`

additionally, you can try Nate's suggestions in the post: http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/11/aem-checkboxes-using-sling-post-servlet. in your case, this would be:

```
<option2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
    fieldLabel="Map Option 2?" 
    name="./option2" 
    width="150" 
    defaultValue="false"
    xtype="checkbox"/>
<option2Type
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
    name="./option2@TypeHint"
    value="Boolean"
    xtype="hidden"/>
```

#### Alternatively. and if you don't want to play with classic widgets, you could just render false when the property does not exist:

```
var showStateLabels = ${properties.option2 ? 'true' : 'false' @context='scriptString'};
```

could also try `context='scriptToken'`, cant remember which one is applicable in this case, but easy to verify.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  The last option worked.  Is there something I can read to learn proper quote notation for sightly in JS?  I was trying to get that same solution to work but couldn't get the quotes in the right place.  I'm struggling now with using the same solution but passing hex color strings instead of booleans, I added it above 'defaultStateColor'. UPDATE: the other answer's syntax worked for the string '${properties.ambetter @context="text"}' ? '#fff' : '#AAA';

Comment: for syntax, see: https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1141-logical-operators. The HTL expression `${}` will evaluate and print in-place. if you use `${properties.ambetter @context="text"}' ? '#fff' : '#AAA` where properties.ambetter is null, you'll end up with `? '#fff' : '#AAA'` which is not a valid Js expression. In any case, if the issue is the context, use `context=unsafe` initially to just test, then use a more restrictive context that applies to your situation.

Comment: I believe that in this case ${properties.option2} will never be null because its evaluating to true or false based on the checkbox.  I would like to fix it but I can't get the hex code strings to come through when they're inside the curly braces, its breaking the javascript.  I don't think context is the issue because context=unsafe also breaks the JS. I imagine my quotes or syntax are incorrect. `${properties.option2 ? '#fff' : '#AAA' @context='unsafe'}`

Comment: Finally got the syntax right.  `'#${properties.option2 ? "fff" : "AAA" @context="text"}';`

Comment: Also works: `'${properties.option2 ? "#fff" : "#AAA" @context="scriptString"}';`

Comment: Oh, that was your issue? Glad you figured it out. And yes, if your outer quotes are single quotes, all your inner quotes should be double quotes and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox is not checked, the property will be empty or will not exist at all in AEM. If the property is *not* empty, you know that the checkbox is checked.
So you can just do something like this:

```
showLabels = '${properties.option2 @context="text"}' ? true : false;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The issue I see with this syntax is, if `properties.option2` is null, the output will be `? true : false;` which is not valid js, that's why I recommended using `${properties.option2 ? 'true' : 'false'}`